# Android - How to draw the vertical and horizontal line

Tags: android, xamarin

I am unable to design with vertical and horizontal line to separate as two/two/two sections (i.e first image on left-side center and second image in right-side center like that three sections) in android design. Can any one help me Please.

```
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/HomeFirstlayout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="-60dp"
android:orientation="vertical">
<ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/TravelRequestimg"
        android:src="@drawable/TravelRequest"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:background="@null"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>              
    <View
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#808080"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" 
        android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"/>                 
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/Settlementimg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/Settlement"
        android:background="@null"/>
     </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/HomeFirstlayout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"                
android:orientation="vertical">
<View
    android:layout_width="1dp"
    android:layout_height="480dp"
    android:background="#808080"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
   </LinearLayout>
  <LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/HomeFirstlayout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
android:layout_marginTop="30dp" 
android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"                    
android:orientation="vertical">
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/TravelRequestimg"
        android:src="@drawable/TravelRequest"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:background="@null"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>              
    <View
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#808080"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" 
        android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"/>                 
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/Settlementimg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/Settlement"
        android:background="@null"/>
  </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Use 

<View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@color/gray" />

to draw horizontal line.
And 

<View
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/gray" />

to draw vertical line

Comment: i already tried .. i got only vertical line from top to end. but horizontal line not joining from left to right.

Comment: Your question is unclear to me, please post some code. I use `TextView` to draw horizontal line, make width as `match_parent` and height as `1dp` or `2dp` depending upon the thickness.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a simple View with width or height 1dp and background color of your line. Or if parent layout of this view are LinearLayout, or TableLayout, TableRow then you can use dividers. i.e

```
android:showDividers="middle"
android:divider="@drawable/your_divider_drawable"
```

**Edit:**
Try this. You just need to set back your ids, and drawables

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="16dp" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/divider"
            android:background="@null"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_delete" />

        <View
            android:id="@id/divider"
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="#808080" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/divider"
            android:background="@null"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_delete" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#808080" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/divider"
            android:background="@null"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_delete" />

        <View
            android:id="@id/divider"
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="#808080" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/divider"
            android:background="@null"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_delete" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#808080" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/divider"
            android:background="@null"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_delete" />

        <View
            android:id="@id/divider"
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="#808080" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/divider"
            android:background="@null"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_delete" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: i think something wrong in my code.i attached above. Can u please help me to solve.

Comment: @user3690793 could you please provide a graphic example of what view you do want to achieve?

Comment: @user3690793 i've updated my answer, you can check if it helps you